# Xamarin Test Cloud using Mac Terminal - Cannot open assembly. No such file or directory

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-test-cloud

I am trying to submit Xamarin.UITests to Xamarin Test Cloud using the Mac Terminal.

testcloud.xamarin.com gives me a url to type into the command line, and when I do, I get this message every time:

Cannot open assembly 'Users/username/.../packages/Xamarin.UITest.2.2.3/tools/test-cloud.exe': No such file or directory.

The file/directory is there. I made sure to provide the whole path, and I clearly see test-cloud.exe file, and yet I get this error.

Does anyone know what might be the issue or how to resolve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my experience just play around with it. Try doing the folder it's in and then the actual thing. Also try and retype the whole code again. I know it might be annoying but it works